# Insert emoji into focused text input

Tags: text, applescript, emoji

How can I make an applescript that inserts an emoji into the focussed text field?

I tried

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "" & return
```

but this puts in `"aa"` rather than the emoji I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with `keystroke`.

Alternatively set the value of attribute `AXSelectedText` of the correspondent UI element to the character for example

```
activate application "TheApp"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "TheApp"
        set value of attribute "AXSelectedText" of text field 1 of window 1 to ""
        keystroke return
   end tell
end tell
```

You can determine the reference to the UI element with UIElementInspector or UI Browser.

Or use the clipboard:

```
set the clipboard to ""
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke return
end tell
```

Comment: But I don't know what application I need to send it to, I just want to send it to the current frontmost/focussed text inpu

Comment: Then you might put the character on the clipboard and send keystroke ⌘V.

Comment: is there a way to reset the clipboard afterwards? Because that almost looks like a perfect solution

Comment: For example empty string: `set the clipboard to ""`

Comment: I mean setting it to previous clipboard contents

Comment: `set temp to the clipboard` `-- do stuff` `set the clipboard to temp`

Comment: Pasteboard is such a creative and odd solution. I don't understand why we can't type emojis but I guess that wasn't a use case when this was designed 15 years ago

Comment: @Sirens How do you **type** emojis on the keyboard? An AppleScript `keystroke` is just the equivalent for pressing the corresponding keys.

Comment: @vadian Not so much emoji I guess but non ASCII. `keystroke` doesn't work with `ñ` and `í`

Comment: @Sirens It **does** work with `ñ` and `í`: `keystroke "n" using option down` `keystroke "n"` and `keystroke "e" using option down` `keystroke "i"`.

Comment: @vadian I often have tabular data in the clipboard that gets 'flattened' to just text when I use this technique.  Any workarounds?

Comment: @AaronParisi Maybe there is another attribute for the tabular data.